# Error with Cauchy prior for MCMClogit

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate a Bayesian logistic model with with a weakly informative Cauchy prior with location=0 and scale=2.5 ([Gelman et al, 2008](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/priors11.pdf)). I am using `MCMClogit` in the `MCMCpack` package:

```
df = read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1791181/MCMC.csv")#Read in data
library(MCMCpack)

logpriorfun <- function(beta, location, scale){
  sum(dcauchy(beta, location, scale, log=T))
} #From the MCMCpack documentation
mcmc.logit = MCMClogit(SECONDARY.LEVEL ~ AGE + SEX + as.factor(DISTRICT), 
                       tune=.25, 
                       user.prior.density=logpriorfun, location=0, scale=2.5, log=T,
                       mcmc=10000, 
                       data=df)
```

But I keep getting the error message below:

```
Error in MCMClogit(SECONDARY.LEVEL ~ AGE + SEX + as.factor(DISTRICT),  :
  REAL() can only be applied to a 'numeric', not a 'NULL'
```

I can't see any obvious problem with either the code or the data. The code runs fine if I take out the prior option. I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) -- "Roasted Marshmallows"
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Comment: I initialized your code with `set.seed(100)`. It showed me the same error as yours in the beginning but then after re-running, it worked perfectly every time (at least four times it did). I guess you might have tried the code many times...

Comment: Indeed. I tried with many permutations and combinations, seeding with either 0 or maximum likelihood estimates.

Comment: Sorry, I meant seeding with different values and using either 0 or ML estimates for beta.start.

Comment: I have the same issue in a Monte Carlo simulation with many iterations of MCMClogit with Cauchy prior. Sometimes the function fails and but re-running on the same data (with different seed) does not replicate the error. It is a very curious problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know the cause of the problem I believe it is relatively save to say that you can re-run `MCMClogit` with different seed to get valid posterior estimates. If you re-run with same seed the error will reoccur. In a Monte Carlo / Re-sampling setting, it seems wise to use `tryCatch` with random seed set in `MCMClogit` to avoid crashing.